# Failed to initialize crash reporting

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

When i try to run my app on my Android device frrom Android Studio I got an error and my app stopped working. Here is the output:

```
I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
E/FirebaseCrash: Failed to initialize crash reporting
                 java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzcce;
                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:94)
                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:178)
                     at com.google.firebase.crash.zze.run(Unknown Source)
                     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzcce;
                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzecz.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
                     at com.google.firebase.crash.zzc.zzbuz(Unknown Source)
                     at com.google.firebase.crash.zzd.call(Unknown Source)
                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
                  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcce" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.yougamestudios.trivial-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.yougamestudios.trivial-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzecz.<clinit>(Unknown Source) 
                     at com.google.firebase.crash.zzc.zzbuz(Unknown Source) 
                     at com.google.firebase.crash.zzd.call(Unknown Source) 
                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
                    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcce
                     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                            ... 8 more
                  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
E/FirebaseCrash: Failed waiting for crash api to load.
                 java.lang.InterruptedException
                     at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1013)
                     at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1302)
                     at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:249)
                     at com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.zzbut(Unknown Source)
                     at com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.zza(Unknown Source)
                     at com.google.firebase.crash.zza.run(Unknown Source)
                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Loading module via FirebaseOptions.
I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
```

I think i need to disable crash reporting from my app but I dont know how can i do it.

Comment: Firebase Crash Reporting is deprecated and its service will stop working very soon. You should be using Crashlytics instead.

Comment: This might not be related but I have experienced similar problem when i reached dex limit and had to add multidex to my application. Especialy i had to inherit MultiDexApplication in my Application class

Comment: Are you using ProGuard?